# Arrow function vs. bound function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

While reading [the article](https://reactarmory.com/guides/learn-react-by-itself/component-instances-and-state) I was a bit confused about the following quote.

> The problem here is that each time an `=>` is encountered, it creates a new copy of the arrow function.

What did the author mean by *a new copy each time*? A new copy of what? What is *each time*? Where can I find a reference which fully encompasses usage and execution flow of arrow function with *creating a new copy each time*?

It would be clear if the author wrote *a new **instance** of the arrow function*. But he wrote *a new **copy** of the arrow function*.
Moreover please don't give me more simplified explanations in comparison with the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) of how arrow function works. Just answer why the author wrote *copy* instead of *instance* or maybe not instead. And answer where that *each time* happens in context of his article and code chunks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow functions inside map in render. React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002265/arrow-functions-inside-map-in-render-react)

Comment: @JoeClay Where did you see `map` in the question? I think it's not a duplicate. The question about `bind` and `=>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760646/bind-in-constructor-or-fat-arrow-in-class/40761947#40761947

Comment: It means that every time the function expression is evaluated, a new function object is instantiated. Which is a thing that you should not do in a react `render` function (just like you shouldn't call `bind` in there).

Comment: What do you feel is wrong with the term "copy"? And really, if you want to remark about word choices, you should just contact the original author. Only he can know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const fn = () => {}
```

is basically the same as old

```
const fn = (function(){}).bind(this);
```

[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a new function on every invocation. That's why it is a good idea to store bound function somewhere instead of creating it on every encounter.

Comment: It would be clearly to understand in case of the author wrote *a new instance of arrow function*. But he wrote *a new copy*. Moreover I see that your answer can tangle another persons since arrow function is not a like binding. If you see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Expression_closures) you can find that arrow function uses `this` value of the enclosing context.

Comment: Author of the article here. This is exactly what I meant. 

Answer (score 1):

It belongs to the fact that arrow function can't use `this` the way you might know it from other things. You can't bind or pass any context to an arrow function. And that `bind` always creates a copy of the function object.

This together explains the example in the article. First off, they use a *normal* function, to be able to bind `this` to it. On the the second step, they overwrite the original `function` object itself with the new copy of the `function` with the correct binding. This is a huge performance boost, because you only have to do it once, and not on any future call.

An example for the `this` problem:

```js
function testNormal() {
  // 'this' is the object, passed below by 'bind'
  console.log(this);
}

var testArrow = () => {
  // 'this' is always the current parent
  // there is no way to pass an other value to 'this' in an arrow function
  console.log(this);
}

testNormal.bind({data: 'test'})();
testArrow.bind({data: 'test'})();
```